# C# Error "Is not supported by the language" after migration to .Net4

Tags: c#, .net, migration

I'm trying to migration our website from .Net 3.5 to 4 and I'm encountering a very weird issue.

Code that works just fine in 3.5 does not anymore once I target .Net4, giving me the error

> "xxx is not supported by the language".

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = !calendarItem.UseUserTimeZone ? user.Settings.TimeZoneInfo : l.TimeZoneItem.Info;
```

On that line of code the error shows on "`.TimeZoneInfo`" and "`.Info`" both of type "`System.TimeZoneInfo`".

Definition of `user.Settings.TimeZoneInfo` property is:

```
public TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneInfo
{
    get { return World.TimeZones[Convert.ToInt32(this[Setting.TimeZoneInfo])].Info; }
    set { this[Setting.TimeZoneInfo] = value.ToTimeZoneItem().Id.ToString(); }
}
```

Definition of `l.TimeZoneItem.Info` property is:

```
public TimeZoneInfo Info
{
    get { return info; }
}
```

Not really sure what's going on here. Need help on that one please.

Comment: I've had this happen when I didn't clear out my bin directory and a certain assembly wouldn't get rebuilt for some reason... deleting it manually from the bin directory did the trick though.

Comment: Agree with John... clean your build. Make sure nothing is there in bin and then rebuild again. Thats how I did resolve it last time.

Comment: That helped narrowing down the problem to a third party assembly we're using. I'm trying to find a .Net 4 compatible version. I'll post back w/ my findings.

Answer (score 20):

It's probably an assembly inconsistency issue.
I had this problem when I wanted to use an assembly that created a circular reference with another project. Once I fixed this circular reference issue, the error didn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 5):

This also happens when a lower library is using a different versionof the .NET Framework.  Had a similar issue and when I updated the Lower Libraries to 3.5 framework and the actual library to the 3.5 framework the problem went away.

Answer (score 5):

For me this occurred due to a missing or out of date `System.ValueTuple` when using multiple return values in c# 7.

The error message is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to call property field differently. Because TimeZoneInfo is also a class in System namespace.

Comment: Properties are explicitly allowed to have the same name as the type that they "contain".

Comment: He isn't saying that the problem is related to the ambiguity between the property and typename, but because TimeInfoZone is also in the (pretty global) `System` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Similiar to Jonathan Perry's answer, in my case I had a reference to an old assembly, not the compiled one. I removed the reference and added it again pointing to the correct dll.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to some of the other posts, in my case I was completely missing a reference to an assembly. It wasn't directly accessed from the project I was working with, but was accessed in another, linked project that I was referencing.

Answer (score 1):

**This also happens when an assembly is missing which is referenced by some other assembly in your project**

Answer (score 0):

Similar to others here, if the referenced assembly is targeted to 'Any CPU', while the current assembly is targeted to 'Any CPU' will cause the problem (at least on a 64 bit machine).