# Elasticsearch NEST 5.x Search Query that is built dynamically

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have the following query that I build piecemeal/dynamically using "&=". Elasticsearch 5.x and Nest 5.x.

```cs
QueryContainer qfilter = null;

qfilter = Query<ClassEL>.Term(m => m.OrderID, iOrderID);

qfilter &= Query<ClassEL>
.Range(r => r
  .Field(f => f.Distance)
  .GreaterThan(100))
&&
.Query<ClassEL>.Term(t => t.Active, true);

 var searchDes = new SearchDescriptor<ClassEL>()
 .From(0)
 .Size(10)
 .Query(qfilter);  <===== *** ERROR HERE ***
```

In Visual Studio, it shows the following error message tip:

```cs
Error: Cannot convert from 'Nest.QueryContainer' to 'System.Func<Nest.QueryContainerDescriptor<ClassEL>, Nest.QueryContainer>'
```

The problem is I can't get the searchDescriptor to accept the query I built. Examples online show Search + Query rolled into one which differs from what I'm trying to accomplish. Below is common example that I want to **avoid**:

```cs
var response = client.Search<Tweet>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Query(q =>
            q.Term(t => t.User, "kimchy")
            || q.Match(mq => mq.Field(f => f.User).Query("nest"))
        )
    );
```

**EDIT:** Using the Andrey's answer works just fine. A problem arises however when I try to get the results back from the search query:

```cs
List<ClassViewEL> listDocuments = response.Documents.ToList();
```

Visual Studio doesn't highlight it as an error immediately, but during compile time has a problem:

> error CS0570:
> 'Nest.ISearchResponse<Website.Common.BizServiceViewEL>.Documents' is
> not supported by the language

Debugging and choosing to **IGNORE** the above error works fine, the code executes just as expected no problems. However the compile time error will prevent code deployments. How can this error be fixed?

**Solution** to EDIT: One of my dependencies in my projects (Newtonsoft.Json.dll) were targeting an older version causing the error to appear. Cleaning the solution and rebuilding fixes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Func<SearchDescriptor<ClassEL>, ISearchRequest>` or pass descriptor in separate method. For example:

```cs
var queryContainer = Query<ClassEL>.Term(x => x.Field(f => f.FirstName).Value("FirstName"));
queryContainer &= Query<ClassEL>.Term(x => x.Field(f => f.LastName).Value("LastName"));

Func<SearchDescriptor<ClassEL>, ISearchRequest> searchFunc = searchDescriptor => searchDescriptor
                                                                                        .Index("indexName")
                                                                                        .Query(q => queryContainer);

var response = _client.Search<ClassEL>(searchFunc);
```

or like this

```cs
ISearchRequest ExecuteQuery(SearchDescriptor<ClassEL> searchDescriptor, QueryContainer queryContainer)
{
    return searchDescriptor.Index("indexName")
        .Query(q => queryContainer);
}

public void GetResults()
{
    var queryContainer = Query<ClassEL>.Term(x => x.Field(f => f.FirstName).Value("FirstName"));
    queryContainer &= Query<ClassEL>.Term(x => x.Field(f => f.LastName).Value("LastName"));

    var response = _client.Search<ClassEL>(s => ExecuteQuery(s, queryContainer));
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit at the end of the question. Did you ever encounter the same bug?

Comment: This is a different question about compilation. I don't have such an issue, but it's discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575076/c-sharp-error-is-not-supported-by-the-language-after-migration-to-net4). Might help

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thanks for pointing me in the right direction